# Convert Datatype of Column while Insert into Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to Change Column data type from 'VarChar' to 'DataType' While inserting into another table from Source Table

I am able to do it in T-SQL

```
Declare @DateTime   As      DateTime
Declare @Date       As      NVARCHAR(20)

Set @Date = '120901'
Set @DateTime = CONVERT(Date,'20'+SUBSTRING(@Date,1,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@Date,3,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@Date,5,2))
Print @DateTime
```

How can i implement it in insert Statement

```
Insert Into AxisReportMain 
Select (Column1,Column2,Column3)
From ReportMain
```

Column2 Contains Date as 'VarChar'. In `AxisReportMain` table  Column2  DataType is "Date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Insert Into AxisReportMain 
Select Column1,
       CONVERT(Date,'20'+SUBSTRING(Column2,1,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(Column2,3,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(Column2,5,2)) as Column2,
       Column3
From ReportMain
Where Column2 <> '000000'
```

Comment: Some Column Value have date like '000000' ..Hence its not working..Solution on this ?

Comment: Is there any way to Convert SQL DateTime value 'Sep 8 2007 9:00PM' To '2007-09-08 21:00:00.000' ???

Comment: Try: `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(30), GetDate(),21)`

Comment: Dont want to Convert it as VarChar. Want it as DateTime Only. But it is returning like Aug 31 2012  9:17PM

Comment: You can only change display format as above. You can also change display fromat in your tool (for example slq managment studio). 
Or you can try use `SET DATEFORMAT`. You can not change the storage format of the date in database.